# Why can this object access methods of it's parent class?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, superclass

This question is taken from an AP Computer Science practice test.

```
public class Bird
{
    public void act()
    {
        System.out.print("fly"); 
        makeNoise(); 
    }
    public void makeNoise()
    {
        System.out.print("chirp"); 
    }
}

public class Dove extends Bird
{
    public void act()
    {
        super.act(); 
        System.out.print("waddle"); 
    }
    public void makeNoise()
    {
        super.makeNoise(); 
        System.out.print("coo"); 
    }
}
```

Suppose the following declaration appears in a class other than Bird or Dove:

```
Bird pigeon = new Dove();
```

What is printed as a result of the call `pigeon.act()`?

I thought the answer would be "fly chirp", but the textbook says that the answer is "fly chirp coo waddle". I thought that 'pigeon' could only access methods available in Bird? I was under the impression that, if the user wanted to access methods in Dove,  'pigeon' would have to be cast to Dove.

Would `Bird pigeon = new Bird();` give the same output? How about `Dove pigeon = new Dove();`?

Comment: Any class can call its parent methods explicitly witht the `super` keyword.

Comment: I understand the functionality of the super keyword. My question was why "Bird pigeon" can access methods in Dove. I thought that "Dove pigeon = new Dove();" would produce "fly chirp coo waddle".

Comment: Hint: call `pigeon.makeNoise()` manually and observe what happens.

Comment: @CarolineYi Sub class inherits all the instance methods from its super parent class. Now sub class has the choice to override the behaviour of the overriden methods. Also using super keyword it can acess or invoke behaviour as defined in its super parent class. Now suggest you to take a notebook and pen and do a dry run of your code. See as how the methods are being invoked. Below answers (including mine) may be helpful.

Comment: just to add if you look the sub class from outside of the sub class then , once a method has been inherited by the sub class then **overriding means modifying the behaviour of same inherited method** , overriding does not mean adding an additional method. Its the internal methods of the sub class which can actually invoke the behaviour of the super parent class method by using `super.`

Comment: Thank you! @nits.kk

Comment: @Caroline if your query is resolved you may opt to choose an answer as accepted or else can let us know about your more doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question "I thought that 'pigeon' could only access methods available in Bird? I was under the impression that, if the user wanted to access methods in Dove, 'pigeon' would have to be cast to Dove." This is actually **true**.

Lets try to find the mssing link in the understanding.

1. When we have code like `Bird pigeon = new Dove();` where `Dove` extends `Bird` we have actual object of `Dove` and reference type is of `Bird`. As the object is of `Dove` so it has  the methods, both **inherited** from super class as well as the ones which are  **added**.
2. Another important point is all the **`overriden`** methods have only one instance. Its Overriden meaning the behavior of the same method has been modified, its not an additional separate method. There is only one copy of inherited method not both. Its the overloaded methods which are separate, just the names are same but signature is different. This is the reason you get the behaviour of Dove when you invoke any overriden method.
3. This one is simple `super` , using it a sub class can access the accessible (visible) entities (instance properties and methods) of its super class. If a sub class uses `super` keyword to invoke a method then its the method of the parent class which gets invoked. But again this can be considered that the author of the sub class did it intentionally. Once the class is written and Objects of such class is created then on the object using `.` (dot operator) users can only invoke whats there in the object. If any method has used `super` keyword its part of the behavior of the object. Users of the Sub class  object can not invoke behavior of the parent class method if its overridden in sub class.
4. Lastly yes if you wish to invoke any additional method of  `Dove` (Sub class ) using a reference of `Bird` (Super class) then you need to cast it to `Dove`.

Answer (score 3):

Long story short, when you access `act` method of `pigeon`, its override from `Dove` is called.

> I thought that 'pigeon' could only access methods available in Bird?

That is certainly true, at least, for situations when no casting is applied. However, method `act` is available on the class `Bird`, the statically known type of `pigeon`, so the call compiles fine.

However, *accessing* methods is only about being able to call them. What methods do when you call them is decided at runtime based on the *dynamic* type of `pigeon`. This is where method overriding comes into play, because `Dove` overrides `Bird`'s methods, but in addition it also calls `Bird`'s methods. That is why the code hits all four printouts.

> Would `Bird pigeon = new Bird();` give the same output?

No, the output would be different, because in this case both dynamic and static types of `pigeon` would be the same, i.e. `Bird`, so only `Bird`'s implementations would be invoked.

Comment: This is also the reason why you must never call overrideable methods from a constructor, as a subclass may have overridden it, making your constructor fragile and potentially insecure.

Answer (score 2):

What you experience here is **polymorphism** in action. And instead of answering your various questions directly; I will simply explain the case you are observing.

You call `act()` on an instance of Dove; that causes a call to super; printing "fly".

That super method then calls `makeNoise()` ... on "itself". But as said: "itself" is a Dove object; thus you get the Dove noise! "coo"!

Then the Dove implementation ends; and prints "waddle".

The **essence** is: the exact *version* of a method that is invoked is determined at **runtime** and it **only** depends on the exact type of the object the method is invoked on.

The above gives you **all** the information you need to answer your other questions yourself. In that sense: don't request answers; ask for explanations; and use those to solve the puzzle yourself!

Answer (score 2):

- the class `Dove` does *override* the methods `act` and `makeNoise` of class `Bird`. Overriding means changing the behavior of a method **visible** to the sub-class, (in your case `Dove`). Methods are visible to a sub-class if they have a `public` or `protected` access modifier or if they have a `package private` access modifier and the sub-class belongs to the same package as the super-class does.
- `pigeon` is an instance of `Dove`.
- calling `pigeon.act()` results in calling `Dove.act`.
- `Dove.act` calls `super.act` which is `Bird.act`.
- `Bird.act` prints `fly` and calls `makeNoise` on `pigeon` resulting in calling `Dove.makeNoise`.
- `Dove.makeNoise` calls `super.makeNoise` which is `Bird.makeNoise`.
- `Bird.makeNoise` print `chirp`.
- `Dove.makeNoise` prints `coo` after calling `super.makeNoice`